# Count how many numbers are divisible by perfect numbers in a given range

Tags: code-golf, number-theory

Given two arbitrary integers \$a\$ and \$b\$, count how many numbers are divisible by [perfect numbers](http://oeis.org/A000396) in that given range (\$a\$ and \$b\$ both are inclusive).

> In mathematics, a perfect number is a positive integer that is the sum
> of its proper positive divisors, that is, the sum of the positive
> divisors excluding the number itself.Equivalently, a perfect number is
> a number that is half the sum of all of its positive divisors
> (including itself), or \$σ(n) = 2n\$.

**Input:**

```
1 100
```

**Output:**

```
18
```

- Use stdin and stdout for Input/Output
- **Your code must handle big integers, so it is not good enough to hard-code a list of perfect numbers.**
- Shortest code wins

Comment: `18` is not a perfect number! I guess you meant `28`? (Since `18!=9+6+3+2+1`, while `28=14+7+4+2+1`).

Comment: @Vereos the question says `Count how many numbers are divisible by perfect numbers `

Comment: Woah, I've been misleaded by the question's name. Thank you!

Comment: @Peter Taylor Arbitrary integers

Comment: Then I suggest you edit the question to make that explicit before people start submitting answers with 32-bit ints.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Is it okay now?

Comment: Well technically `1` is perfect...

Comment: How arbitrary is "arbitrary"? Is it enough to work within a language's limitations? (e.g.: AFAIK, PowerShell can only go up to 2^96-1)

Comment: @mniip, no it isn't. The empty set adds to 0, not 1.

Comment: @Iszi, PowerShell can use `System.Numerics.BigInteger`, surely?

Comment: @PeterTaylor First I've heard of it, but I'm also relatively new to this. I'll look into it. So far I've found that it is not built-in for PS 2.0 - you need 3.0 or later which is not installed by default on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Perl 6, <s>106</s> 103 characters

```
my ($a,$b)=get.words;(($a..$b).grep: *%%any ($a..$b).grep: {$^n==[+] ($^n%%$_&&$_ for 1..^$^n)})[*.say]
```

There's a lot of syntax here, so hopefully this explanation helps at least a little to someone who knows a bit of Perl 5 syntax, though I won't explain every detail:

Finds all the perfect numbers in the range $a..$b: `($a..$b).grep: {$^n==[+] ($^n%%$_&&$_ for 1..^$^n)}` (explained below). It then chooses all the numbers in the range $a..$b which are divisible (`%%`) by any of the perfect numbers it had found: `(%a..%b).grep: * %% any …`.

The final `(…)[*.say]` abuses the fact that any code (in this case `*.say`, which prints its argument and a newline) passed to the `[…]` postfix will be given the list's length as its argument (so that one can, e.g., use the idiomatic `@array[*-1]` to get the last element of `@array`). This means that the `(…)[*.say]` here has the same effect as `say (…).elems`.

The part that finds all the perfect numbers in the range does so by returning only those numbers which are equal (`$^n ==`) to the sum of their divisors. `[+]` adds together the values following it, `for 1..^$^n` iterates over all numbers 1 to $^n-1 and assigns $_ to them, and `$^n %% $_ && $_` returns $_ if $^n is divisible (`$^n %% $_`) by $_, or else `False`, thus creating a list that consists of the proper divisors of $^n and `False` objects, which numify to 0 when all the values are added together by `[+]`.

Perl 6 uses arbitrary sized integers, so, if you have the resources and the time, it could technically compute for big integers

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica - 117

Naive approach, linear for the range size

```
With[{p=#(#+1)/2&/@Select[2^Range@@Floor@Log2@Sqrt@#-1,PrimeQ]},Length@Select[Range@@#,Or@@Divisible[#,p]&]]&@Input[]
```

The correct way would be constructing numbers from the perfect numbers that are in the given range of course.

Answer (score 3):

## C, <s>125</s>120

```
a,b,c,p[4]={6,28,496,8128};main(i){for(scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);a<=b;a++)for(i=0;i<4;)if(a%p[i++]==0)c++,i=4;printf("%d",c);}
```

A little more readable:

```
a,b,c=0,i,p[4]={6,28,496,8128};
main()
{
    for(scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);a<=b;a++)
        for(i=0;i<4;)
            if(a%p[i++]==0)
            {
                c++;
                i=4;
            }
    printf("%d",c);
}
```

This works with signed 32bit integers, up to **2^31-1=2147483647**.

## C, <s>212</s>209

```
#include<stdint.h>
uint64_t a,b,c,p[8]={6,28,496,8128,33550336,8589869056,137438691328,0x1fffffffc0000000};main(i){for(scanf("%lld%lld",&a,&b);a<=b;a++)for(i=0;i<8;)if(a%p[i++]==0)c++,i=8;printf("%lld",c);}
```

Should work up to **2^64-1=18446744073709551615**.

Comment: In C global ints are initialized to 0 by default so you don't need to set c=0 :)

Comment: To save 1 char you could move one of your ints into the main declaration, ex `main(i)` (saves a comma character).

Comment: Oh, you're right! I also removed a couple of useless `{}`.

Comment: You can remove the pair of braces around your if statement by changing the contents to be `c++,i=4;`

Comment: Yes, I did it. Well, not in the prettified version, but that's not supposed to be short, isn't it?

Comment: Ah I missed that!

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell - 157

```haskell
c x=x==sum[i|i<-[1..x-1],mod x i==0]
d x=any((0==).mod x)$takeWhile(<=x)(filter c[2..])
main=do m<-getLine;n<-getLine;print$length(filter d[read m..read n])
```

Can work with arbitrarily large numbers given respectively large time.
Input is given on 2 lines.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3 [166 bytes]

```
a,b=map(int,input().split());print(len(set([n if n%p==0 else 0 for p in [x for x in range(a,b) if sum(y for y in range(1,x) if x%y==0)==x] for n in range(a,b+1)]))-1)
```

More readable:

```
// STDIN => a, b
a, b = map(int, input().split())

// list of perfect numbers
perfect = [x for x in range(a, b) if sum(y for y in range(1, x) if x % y == 0) == x]

// length(number % [any perfect number] == 0) => STDOUT
print(len(set([n if n % p == 0 else 0 for p in perfect for n in range(a, b + 1)])) - 1)
```

Here the list of perfect numbers is calculated inline but may be set statically. The number range should be bound by the machine's word size.

<sub>While this algorithm is deadly slow and takes ages for working with big numbers, it is at least short `:)`</sub>

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
rÆD=Æṣ$§TL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/ocJuL7eG2hzsXqxxaHuLz//9/w/@GBgYA)

Requiring space separated STDIN input bumps the byte count up to [15 bytes](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//yaDhuLJW4oKsci/DhkQ9w4bhuaMkwqdUTP//MSAxMDA)

### How it works

```
rÆD=Æṣ$§TL - Main link. Takes a on the left and b on the right
r          - Yield [a, a+1, ..., b-1, b]
 ÆD        - Generate the divisors of each
      $    - Over each list of divisors, d:
    Æṣ     -   Generate the proper divisor sum of each value in d
   =   §   -   Count how many are equal to their proper divisor sum
             This maps numbers with perfect to divisors to a non-zero value
             and those without to 0
        TL - Count the number of non-zero elements
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=sum,any -pl`, 77 bytes

```perl
$"=$_,$\+=any{$"%$_==0}grep{//;2*$_==sum grep{$'%$_==0}1..$_}2..$"for$_..<>}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19FyVYlXkclRts2Ma@yWkVJVSXe1tagNr0otaBaX9/aSAvELy7NVQCLqKhD5Q319FTia42ApFJafpFKvJ6ejV1t9f//hlyGBgb/8gtKMvPziv/r@vpkFpdYWYWWZOaADNEB2vFftyAHAA)

Ungolfed:

```
$_ = ; # implicit by -p command line switch
for$_($_..){ # loop over the range from $_ to the next input
   $"=$_;                           # store a copy of the current number ($_) so it can be used in sub-loops
   $\+=                             # counter for number of perfectly divisible numbers found
      any{$"%$_==0}                 # check if the current number ($") is evenly divisible by a:
         grep{//;2*$_==             # PERFECT NUMBER: a number where twice the number equals
            sum grep{$'%$_==0}1..$_ #                 the sum of the numbers which divide it evenly
         }2..$"                     # that exists in range of 2 to the current number
}
print$\; # implicit by -p command line switch
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 11 bytes

```
ṡƛ'∆K=;Ḋa;∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuaHGmyfiiIZLPTvhuIphO+KIkSIsIiIsIjEwMFxuMSJd)

[9 bytes with `s` flag](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwi4bmhxpsn4oiGSz074biKYSIsIiIsIjEwMFxuMSJd)

[12 bytes accounting for space seperated inputs](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLEluG5ocabJ+KIhks9O+G4imE74oiRIiwiIiwiMSAxMDAiXQ==)

### Explained

```
ṡƛ'∆K=;Ḋa;∑
ṡƛ       ;  # Over each item x in the range [input a, input b]
  '∆K=;     #   Keep items from the range [1, x] that are perfect numbers
       Ḋa   #   And is x divisible by any of those perfect numbers?
          ∑ # Sum the number of numbers that are divisible by a perfect number
```